# Strategies for mutation operations of immutable value objects

Tags: domain-driven-design, immutability

According to DDD principles, it's often advised that value objects be used to encode values which don't have a life cycle of their own, but are merely values. By design, such objects are made immutable. They often replace primitives, which makes the code more semantic and error-safe.

The rationale is very sensible, but sometimes it leads to some cumbersome operations. For example, consider the case where an address is encoded as a value object along the lines of:

```
class Address extends ValueObject {
    public Address(String line1, String line2, String postalCode, String String country) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

In an application, it wouldn't be unusual for a user to change only one field of an address. In order to achieve that in code, one would have to do something like:

```
String newCity = ...;

Address newAddress = new Address(
    oldAddress.getLine1(),
    oldAddress.getLine2(),
    oldAddress.getPostalCode(),
    newCity,
    oldAddress.getCountry());
```

This could lead to some very repetitive and overly verbose code. What are some good strategies for avoiding this, while keeping immutable value objects?

My own ideas:

1. Private setters, which could enable helper methods like this:

   ```
   public Address byChangingPostalCode(String newPostalCode) {
       Address newAddress = this.copy();
       newAddress.setPostalCode(newPostalCode);
       return newAdress;
   }
   ```

   A downside is that the object now isn't immutable anymore, but as long as that's kept private, it shouldn't be a problem, right…?
2. Make the value object a full-fledged entity instead. After all, the need for fields to be modified over a longer time indicates that it does have a life cycle. I'm not convinced by this though, as the question regards developer convenience rather than domain design.

I'll happily receive your suggestions!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your suggestions! I'll go with private setters and corrective methods.

Comment: Use languages where immutable types are first class citizens. Example in F# : `let newAddress = { oldAddress with PostalCode = 10005 }`

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with having immutable values return other immutable values.

```
Address newAddress = oldAddress.correctPostalCode(...);
```

This is my preferred approach within the domain model.

Another possibility is to use a builder

```
Address new Address = AddressBuilder.from(oldAddress)
                      .withPostalCode(...)
                      .build()
```

I don't like that one as much, because `build` isn't really part of the ubiquitous language.  It's a construction I'm more likely to use in a unit test, where I need a whole address to talk to the API  but the test itself only depends on a subset of the details.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the builder pattern. Whereas I agree that it should be kept out of the domain, it could be used privately or, as you say, for testing.

Comment: Why must they be entirely replaced by other immutable values? My understanding of value objects is that they are a snapshot of time, and do not have a lifecycle of their own. If I modify a value object directly, I am not giving this object any additional lifetime which it did not have before.

Answer (score 1):

> Private setters, which could enable helper methods like this:

This is my preferred solution for *changing* a Value object. The naming of the method should be from the ubiquitous language but this can be combined to a team/programming language convention. In PHP there is a known convention: immutable command method names start with the word "with". For example `withCorrectedName($newName)`.

The object must not be fully constant but only act as such in order to be considered immutable.

> Make the value object a full-fledged entity instead.

It wouldn't be a ValueObject anymore, so don't!

Comment: Sticking to a convention for naming these methods is very sensible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with derive methods:

```
Address newAddress = oldAddress.derive( newPostalCode);

Address newAddress = oldAddress.derive( newLine1 );
```

And so on...